# Can big solder joints in a PCB power path introduce noise, and extra socket question

Tags: pcb-design, socket

[image]

The green line labels at the left (near the center) of the PCB are connected to the AD620 ground lines. The red lines parallel it are connected to +Vs.

I plan to experiment with injecting different -Vs value into it. My concern is that I have to cut the PCB copper line and solder a wire to connect to my dual power supply.

1. First question after the experiment, I will put them back by putting big solder joints (because I can't do it as tiny and narrow as the original traces) to connect them back together. Can this produce noise, or is it harmless?
2. Second question.
   Do you know of any extra socket on top of an existing socket (you can see the left AD620 chips have sockets on them) which I can put on top of the AD620 sockets so I can separately power the Vs and -Vs (remember, just testing what would happen) without cutting the bottom of the PCB but just kind of tapping it from the extra above socket? Are there techniques or device for this procedure?

This is the front of the PCB.

[image]

Zoomed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I plan to experiment with injecting different -Vs value into it. My
> concern is that I have to cut the PCB copper line and solder a wire to
> connect to my dual power supply. After the experiment, I will put them
> back by putting big solders (because I can't do it as tiny and narrow
> as them) to connect them back together. Can this produce noise, or is
> it harmless?

If you are cutting V-, and resoldering it, it wouldn't be a big deal since the PSRR is going to reject most noise that trace cutting could cause. The problem of cutting a trace is it introduces a bit more resistance in the power rail which as long as you keep the trace cutting and fix lower than something 100mΩ you should be fine, but you should be able to do much better than that. A copper wire instead of just solder is also better.

But one problem is the loads of the power rails are daisy chained. The traces could be thicker and there is no ground on the PCB that would help with shielding. Checking the rails for noise would be good, I can't see any voltage regulators on the analog side of the board which isn't a good sign if you want to have low noise power rails (they could be on the digital side).

> Do you know of any extra socket on top of an existing socket (you can
> see the left AD620 chips have sockets on them) which I can put on top
> of the AD620 sockets so I can separately power the Vs and -Vs
> (remember, just testing what would happen) without cutting the bottom
> of the PCB but just kind of tapping it from the extra above socket?
> Are there techniques or device for this procedure?

If you carefully bend the pins of the AD620 you might be able to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: There is a voltage regular transistor on the lower right. It's an LM78L05 which converts any voltage input (say 9 volts) to 5 volts. Is this the voltage regulator on the analog side you were looking for that can create low noise power rail? Or is it another voltage regulator that is required. What is it? The second transistor in the picture is just an undervoltage detector MC34064 which resets the HC11 if the voltage got low.

Comment: This is the correct technique:  >>  If you carefully bend the pins of the AD620 you might be able to accomplish the same thing.  <<   PUll the chip, use tweezers to bend the power pins to point straight out.  Reset the chip, and it'll be a breeze to solder wires to the power pins.